# get result of order in magento via API

Tags: php, api, soap

it try to create order from shopping cart in magento via API , first i set customer, customer address, shipping and payment methods and it`s return me true then i use this code to create order

```
$orderId = $proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId);
```

and it`s return to me this error :

> SOAP-ENV:Server
>   Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-objectError in shoppingOrder

but when i check orders in magento admin panel , order is created and added to table in panel ! i set phone number for customer informaton , shipping info and , billing info .
can any body help me to find problem ?
thanks

Comment: Would be great if you could add your cart details. Please add your solution as your own answer and accept it, if you solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there was no response from the OP for a long time.